# Undefined is not a function - MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I keep getting undefined is not a function for the line below

`Institutions.insert({$set: {admin: Meteor.userId(), title: inst_name, type: inst_type, school: inst_school, description: inst_desc}, $push: {members: Meteor.userID()}});`

Here's the full snippet in context. Would someone explain how to correct this error and what's causing it?

https://bpaste.net/show/f1e1c993cc0b

Comment: Replace `Meteor.userID()` with `Meteor.userId()`?

Comment: Oh, silly mistake. @DavidWelon would you chat request? Having trouble, getting Access Denied on the line as well. Can't put full code here as it's private.

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake -- Meteor.userID() needs to be changed to Meteor.userId()